# How to center text within a fade in overlay using html and css?

Tags: html, css, hover, media-queries, mousehover

I came across this [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_image_overlay_fade), which provides me with instructions on how to create an image that turns to text when the image is hovered over it

However, my text is too large for the image, so I'm trying to decrease the margins of the hover overlay.

I changed the .text class so that the top and left are 20% and also changed the transform attribute as well as the ms-transform attribute. But the issue is now that the text is no longer centered

See my code below and [codepen here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WyWoVK)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: #008CBA;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 20%;
  transform: translate(-20%, -20%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-20%, -20%);
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Fade in Overlay</h2>
<p>Hover over the image to see the effect.</p>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://s4827.pcdn.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/stack_overflow_logo.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.


</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that the text is not centered (see below):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So depending on how you want it to look Ive found two different ways, most likely many more can be found.

1. Remove the transforms and add `right: 20%;` as well which looks like this: 
   https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YvMNje
2. Remove the transforms and the left: 20%; and it will look like this: 
   https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xzegaq

Answer (score 1):

chris

you just need EDIT your .text transform.

your fixed code is here

```
    .text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```